# How to export data from AWS RDS MySQL database and import to an other AWS RDS MySQL database instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, etl

I am looking for the best way to export data from one MySQL DB instance of RDS an import into a different one **automatically**.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Best" according to what criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of copy an entire database is to create a read replica of the original and promote this read replica into a separate database.